# We are getting "a.tmpl.complete is not a function" with v1.9

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

We are getting the following error with v1.9 of the profiler.

> a.tmpl.complete is not a function

Search and tried looking into issue but so far no luck on what to do to correct it.

Anyone else know what to do?

Comment: sounds like an issue / conflict with jquery.tmpl http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/ are you already using in on your page? perhaps a version thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is collateral damage caused by the never ending fight for jQuery to get a templating engine.

What happened was that jQuery.tmpl was going to be the templating engine the jQuery team were going to bless. However stuff happened and for whatever reason the current contender may be [jsRender](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=118).

If for any reason you depended on a particular **different** implementation of `$.tmpl` depending on ordering Mini Profiler would either break you or you would break Mini Profiler.

To overcome this I just patched MiniProfiler to use an unobtrusive version of jQuery and jQuery.tmpl. This means you can load whatever version of jQuery you want into your page but MiniProfiler will only use a special "renamed" version of jQuery (stored in the global jQueryMP)

See also: [Unobtrusive jQuery html templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256254/unobtrusive-jquery-html-templating)